# Discrete Logarithm Problem used in currently used cryptosystems

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, elliptic-curves, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

Is it incorrect to say "Many important algorithms in public-key cryptosystems used at present have their security based on the assumption that the Discrete Logarithm Problem (DLP) over some chosen finite groups has no efficient solution. The groups taken for currently used cryptosystems, that are considered to have intractable DLP are, $\mathbb{Z}_n^{*}$ and cyclic subgroups of elliptic curves over finite fields $\mathbb{Z}_p$." $p$ is a prime and $n$ will be a product of two primes $pq$.

If there is an error in the above statement please kindly explain me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may be a more appropriate question for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay thanks a lot @Condo I will try there as well.

Comment: Not trying to nitpick, but there are *two* statements (sentences) in the quoted passage.  The first I understand to describe "many public key cryptosystems" (and it seems unobjectionable), while the second seems possibly to relate what topics are about to be discussed in a paper or talk.  Context please?

Comment: Thanks a lot @hardmath yes actually it's 2 sentences :) There are similar descriptions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm . No particular context...I don't remember whether I got it from a particular source, but I have written these sentences in a note. I was doubtful about specifying as $\mathbb{Z}_n^{*}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: Closely related older Questions: ["Discrete logarithm problem in many groups of cryptographic interest"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24162/discrete-logarithm-problem-in-many-groups-of-cryptographic-interest) and [Groups where discrete logarithm is hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63523/groups-where-discrete-logarithm-is-hard?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you very much @hardmath